# Installshield MDI dialogs

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, mdiparent

I want to show multiple dialogs over one dialog. Does anyone can suggest how to achieve this MDI parent and child relationship in Installshield?

Appreciate your response ASAP.

Regards,
Anoop